# hosted app for firefox os similar to: http://www.zoobe.com/, is it possible?

Tags: firefox, operating-system, firefox-os

I'm currently working  at a project to develop an App for firefox os similar to: http://www.zoobe.com/.

So it's basicly a hosted app, where you can choose a 3D-character. Then you have to make a picture for the background and record your voice on the phone. A Video will be rendered then and the 3d-character will speak the recorded message for you!

So my generell question is: Does anybody know, if its possible to develop such complex app for firefox os at this stage? 
I've read, that all the APIs required for the project, like camera API and so on are already working.

I would implement the data-flow between server and client with node.js. 
I would be greatful for any evaluations, tips and help.

Comment: OT but nice links about what you can do here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/02/using-webapis-to-make-the-web-layer-more-capable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sound recording API yet, so I fear you will have to wait for it to be implemented for this kind of app to be possible. You can track the work on this API at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=803414